# Don't quite understand SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have read a lot about sql injection and I understand how it could cause problems (ie: DROP TABLE *_*_ etc). But I am unsure how the tutorials I have followed actually prevent this from happening. I am just learning PDO and I think I understand it.

**Is this code safe from SQL injection?** and why is it? (It takes quite a bit more work using these prepared statements so I want to be sure I am not just wasting my time - **also if the code can be improved please let me know!**)

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_DATABASE",$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);

// Get the data
$firstname = $_POST["v_firstname"];
$lastname =  $_POST["v_lastname"];
$origincountry =  $_POST["v_origincountry"];
$citizenship = $_POST["v_citizenship"];
$gender = $_POST["v_gender"];
$dob = $_POST["v_dob"];
$language = $_POST["v_language"];
$landing = $_POST["v_landing"];
$email = $_POST["v_email"];
$phone = $_POST["v_phone"];
$cellphone = $_POST["v_cellphone"];
$caddress = $_POST["v_caddress"];
$paddress = $_POST["v_paddress"];
$school = $_POST["v_school"];
$grade = $_POST["v_grade"];
$smoker = $_POST["v_smoker"];
$referred = $_POST["v_referred"];
$notes = $_POST["v_notes"];


//Insert Data
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (firstname, lastname, origincountry, citizenship, gender, dob, language, landing, email, phone, cellphone, caddress, paddress, school, grade, smoker, referred, notes) 
        VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :origincountry, :citizenship, :gender, :dob, :language, :landing, :email, :phone, :cellphone, :caddress, :paddress, :school, :grade, :smoker, :referred, :notes)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':firstname'=>$firstname,
                  ':lastname'=>$lastname,
                  ':origincountry'=>$origincountry,
                  ':citizenship'=>$citizenship,
                  ':gender'=>$gender,
                  ':dob'=>$dob,
                  ':language'=>$language,
                  ':landing'=>$landing,
                  ':email'=>$email,
                  ':phone'=>$phone,
                  ':cellphone'=>$cellphone,
                  ':caddress'=>$caddress,
                  ':paddress'=>$paddress,
                  ':school'=>$school,
                  ':grade'=>$grade,
                  ':smoker'=>$smoker,
                  ':referred'=>$referred,
                  ':notes'=>$notes));
```

Comment: When you use prepared statements, the SQL engine can parse the query separately from the dynamic input - user input can no longer change the meaning of the query.

Comment: I think it is. SQL injection occurs when you concatenate user input to SQL statement: like `'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' + id';` because user input (`id` here) could be harmful (for example: `id = '1; DROP TABLE users';`)

Comment: see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @RC., Wikipedia is hardly a reliable source. Yes, it is more or less accurate, but remember that because it is a public wiki, pranksters do mess with it, so other sources are far more valuable than wikipedia

Comment: @PranavHosangadi If you don't want to trust a public wiki, why are you here?

Comment: @JensSchauder, just saying wikipedia is not reliable enough to be quoted as a source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the code is safe, as PDO will properly escape and quote the array of parameters for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is safe from SQL injection because you're using paramaterized query, which basically means that once the query is being built and sent to the sql server, it's being escaped, same could be achieved by using php's built in function `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

The following video is great informational video about sql injection from OWASP:
[SQL Injection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pypTYPaU7mM)

Answer (score 0):

The rule is: Do not construct sql by hand, in which you do something like:

```
sqlStatement = 'select field1, field2, field3 from mytable where index = '' + myVariable + ''
```

The above is dangerous, because if your app allows a user to pass data into myVariable, they could potentially send full SQL commands to your db server.

Using parameterized queries, as you do above, is the solution.